# Link error in Boost program_options code on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu, hyperlink

I installed boost on ubuntu 10.04 by

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
```

I think after that I don't need to set any -I and -L flags, so I compile my code by

```
g++ test.cpp
```

Here is my test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/detail/config_file.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/parsers.hpp>

namespace pod = boost::program_options::detail;

int main() 
{  
    //contents
    std::stringstream s(
            "a = 1\n"
            "b = 2\n"
            "c = test option\n");
    //parameters
    std::set<std::string> options;
    options.insert("a");
    options.insert("b");
    options.insert("c");

    //parser
    for (pod::config_file_iterator i(s, options), e ; i != e; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i->value[0] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I think things will goes well but actually there are some errors:

```
/tmp/ccNQEbJM.o: In function `boost::program_options::detail::basic_config_file_iterator<char>::basic_config_file_iterator(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool)':
a.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options6detail26basic_config_file_iteratorIcEC1ERSiRKSt3setISsSt4lessISsESaISsEEb[boost::program_options::detail::basic_config_file_iterator<char>::basic_config_file_iterator(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool)]+0x24): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::common_config_file_iterator::common_config_file_iterator(std::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool)'
a.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options6detail26basic_config_file_iteratorIcEC1ERSiRKSt3setISsSt4lessISsESaISsEEb[boost::program_options::detail::basic_config_file_iterator<char>::basic_config_file_iterator(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool)]+0x5f): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::common_config_file_iterator::get()'
/tmp/ccNQEbJM.o: In function `boost::eof_iterator<boost::program_options::detail::common_config_file_iterator, boost::program_options::basic_option<char> >::increment()':
a.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12eof_iteratorINS_15program_options6detail27common_config_file_iteratorENS1_12basic_optionIcEEE9incrementEv[boost::eof_iterator<boost::program_options::detail::common_config_file_iterator, boost::program_options::basic_option<char> >::increment()]+0x10): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::common_config_file_iterator::get()'
/tmp/ccNQEbJM.o: In function `boost::program_options::detail::basic_config_file_iterator<char>::getline(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
a.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options6detail26basic_config_file_iteratorIcE7getlineERSs[boost::program_options::detail::basic_config_file_iterator<char>::getline(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)]+0x5b): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't figure out where and why I went wrong.

Comment: You never linked to the boost libraries. You do need to specify the appropriate `-l` options.

Comment: by how? I install boost by sudo apt-get install libboost-dev. I don't down where is the libraries. I specify by "g++ test.cpp -lboost-program_options" but fail to load lboost-program_options.

Comment: It's all underscore, you have a '-' after boost which should be '_'

Comment: I try "g++ test.cpp -lboost_program_options", fail again. Error message:/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Did I miss to do something? Or link the incorrect library name?

Comment: Where can I find the libraries? /usr/lib? And Where can I get the name of the library like program_options?

Answer (score 17):

You need to *link* to the Boost program_options library as not everything in Boost is pure templates:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ cat bpoex.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/detail/config_file.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/parsers.hpp>

namespace pod = boost::program_options::detail;

int main() 
{  
    //contents
    std::stringstream s(
            "a = 1\n"
            "b = 2\n"
            "c = test option\n");
    //parameters
    std::set<std::string> options;
    options.insert("a");
    options.insert("b");
    options.insert("c");

    //parser
    for (pod::config_file_iterator i(s, options), e ; i != e; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i->value[0] << std::endl;
    }
}
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ -o bpoex bpoex.cpp -lboost_program_options
edd@max:/tmp$ ./bpoex
1
2
test option
edd@max:/tmp$
```

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status    why I can't link boost_program_options?

Comment: I know where did I miss. It's embarrassed that "sudo apt-get install libboost-dev" do not install library program_options. I need to install it by "sudo apt-get libboost-program-options-dev". After that, I can use "g++ test.cpp -lboost_program_options" to compile like what you just did. Thanks Dirk, David, fefe.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev" will install all boost libraries.

Comment: Good to know you have it working. It is customary here to 'upvote' good answers and also 'accept' answers as solutions if they fit. You can do that by clicking at the symbols at the top-left of the post.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel out of curiousity, if you hadn't told us the library name (`boost_program_options`), how does one go about finding it? Do we have to know a guy who knows a guy who knows the guy that wrote the library?