# undefined reference to boost::program_options in xubuntu

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have this file

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    try {

    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help", "produce help message")
        ;

    }
    catch(exception& e) {
        cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    catch(...) {
        cerr << "Exception of unknown type!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now I am trying to compile like this:

> g++ -I /usr/include/boost/ -I /usr/include/boost/program_options
>   main.cpp -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_program_options

and I am receiving this

> undefined reference to
>   `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)'

I don't know why it is failing, the library is there and the header file too. What goes wrong? I am using boost 1.55.0

```
administrator@administrator-VirtualBox:~/l/b$ sudo updatedb
administrator@administrator-VirtualBox:~/l/b$ locate libboost_program_options
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0
```

Comment: Can you do a `sudo updatedb` followed by a `locate libboost_program_options` and paste the results of the latter?

Comment: please see the updated question

Comment: It looks OK. Sorry, I don't know. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link error in Boost program\_options code on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8652096/608639)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like boost was compiled with pre-C++11 `std::basic_string`, whereas your code is compiled with C++11 `std::basic_string`.

Try re-compiling your code with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` compiler command line option. See [GCC5 and the C++11 ABI](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/) for more details:

> In most cases, it will be obvious when this flag is needed because of errors from the linker complaining about unresolved symbols involving `__cxx11`.

Comment: another way to work around this is to give `--with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible` when compiling gcc/g++